# SQL Corr Command/Order By

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT ROUND(CORR(ProductStandardPrice, OrderedQuantity), 3) AS Price_Quantity_Correlation
FROM Product_T P, Orderline_T L
WHERE P.ProductID = L.ProductID;
```

Just wondering what the 3 is after the `productStandardPrice` and `Orderedquantity`?

What does the 3 do? I can't find any information of that on the internet.

Also when you do Orderby # say 3 is it ordering by the 3rd column or by how?

Answer (score 0):

That should be the number of significant figures we're keeping from the number given by "CORR(ProductStandardPrice, OrderedQuantity)".

Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm

Also yes, the number should be the column number from the table.
Reference the documentation again: (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/ROUND-number.htm#SQLRF00698), `round(n, [x])` returns `n` rounded to `x` places to the right of the decimal point. 
For example:

```
SQL> select round(0.12345, 3) from dual;

ROUND(0.12345,3)
----------------
            ,123
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SELECT.htm#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2171079) also explains that `order by n` means "order by the Nth column".

Also, again in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046), Oracle recommends to use the ANSI JOIN instead of the old Oracle join operator.